# Prove $p(x)=\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$ with $x=1,2,3,\ldots$ is a probability function and calculate $E[X]$

Tags: probability

Prove $p(x)=\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$ with $x=1,2,3,\ldots$ is a probability function and calculate $\operatorname E[X]$

**My work**

$p$ is a probability function if $p(x_i)\geq 0 $ and $\sum_{x\in X}\frac{1}{x(x+1)}=1$

Well,

$p(x_i)\geq 0$ for $x_i=i\in\mathbb{N}$ is trivial.

$$\sum_{x\in X}\frac{1}{x(x+1)}=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$

Then, the partial sum, is:

$$\sum_{x=1}^k\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}=1-\frac{1}{k+1}$$

This implies:
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}1-\frac{1}{k+1}=1$$

In consequence, $\sum p(x)=1$

For the expected value:

$$\operatorname E[X]=\sum_{x\in X} xp(x)=\sum\frac{1}{x+1}$$

Here i'm little stuck. I thin that series diverges. Can someone review me? Thanks for all!

Comment: That's it, the expectation is $\infty$. That's the point of the exercise, to show you an example in which that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You've done everything right. And, yes, the sum for $E[X]$diverges. Hence, the random variables has no expected value (you could also say that $E[X]=+\infty$).

To show that the series diverge, notice that $\sum_{x=1}^N\frac{1}{x+1}=\sum_{k=2}^N\frac{1}{k}=-1+\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k}$
where the last sum is the [harmonic sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), which diverges.